# how to set splash screen always in landscape mode in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp

i am trying to set splash screen always in landscape mode on uwp platform by Checking checkbox "landscape" on Supported rotations in Package.appxmanifest. 
Any resolution.
Refer image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt3vu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want that. The image you are providing is not going to take the entire screen up, it is only centered in the page.  I think your settings are doing what they are supposed to but you are expecting to see something that you won't ever see as you image will not "fill" the splashscreen.

Comment: how to open a splash screen always in landscape mode in uwp platform specially in windows 10 mobile.